# Cryptic F# error - The signature and implementation are not compatible because the declaration of the type parameter requires a constraint of 'T=null

Tags: wpf, f#

I have a small piece of F# code that is generating a cryptic error I can't figure out....

```
namespace epic.View

open System
open FSharp.Desktop.UI

[<AbstractClass>]
type public FieldModelBase<'ValueType>() = 
    inherit Model() 
    let mutable fieldCaption: string = null
    let mutable fieldValue: 'ValueType = null
    [<DerivedProperty>]
    member this.Caption with public get() = sprintf "%s" fieldCaption and set value = fieldCaption <- sprintf "%s" value; this.NotifyPropertyChanged "Caption"
    [<DerivedProperty>]
    member inline this.Value with public get() = fieldValue and set value = fieldValue <- value; this.NotifyPropertyChanged "Value"
```

which generates the following error:

> The signature and implementation are not compatible because the
>   declaration of the type parameter 'ValueType' requires a constraint of
>   the form 'ValueType : null

What does this mean and how do I resolve it? It looks like I should be adding a type constraint on the 'ValueType type-parameter to require it is... mutable? is that right?

Comment: I think it is trying to say that valuetype needs to be nullable - I think `<'ValueType:null>` should do it or otherwise use `Operators.Unchecked.defaultOf` instead of `null` when you initiailise fieldvalue.

Comment: Also, `sprintf "%s" value` is equivalent to just `value`, only slower.

Comment: `type public FieldModelBase<'ValueType when 'ValueType : null>() =` did it for me

Comment: Thanks, everyone. @Onur 's solution worked for me

Comment: Also, @FyodorSoikin - correct, but I don't want that. Since value is mutable, i'd prefer an empty string to a null, and sprintf was just too easy to inline. ;-)